# JSON_ARRAYAGG returns a truncated list of data

Tags: json, oracle, json-arrayagg

I am trying to create a JSON output but it is displayed truncated.

Table creation and inserts:

```
create table test(c1 number, c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(100));

begin
  for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
    insert into test values (i, 'val_' || i, 'descption of ' || i);
  end loop;
end;
```

SQL query I execute:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           distinct JSON_OBJECT(
                   'id' VALUE c1,
                   'value' VALUE c2,
                   'description'  VALUE c3) RETURNING CLOB)
  FROM test;
```

Here it is the output:

> [{"id":1,"value":"val_1","description":"descption
> of 1"

I am using Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 database version and SQL Developer  Version 23.1.1.339, Build 339.1213

Can anyone help me to understand what should I do to get all the rows, please?

Thank you,

Comment: which tool are you using to execute the sql? if sqlplus, then do set long xxxx longc yyy before. xxxx should be high enough for the expected size of the clob

Comment: I am using SQL Developer.

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m5oFlbXx). Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with details of the version of Oracle database you are using and of the client application (i.e. SQL Developer) that you are using to talk to the database.

Comment: I added required details

Comment: the script output in sqldev will truncate the output unless you also use 'set long xxxx'. The grid output will show the full length if you click the pencil after double-clicking the row

Comment: I used set long 2000000 but same behavior occurs

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, it seems I solved the problem by an workaround.

The workaround consist in changing the data type from RETURNING clause from CLOB to VARCHAR2(32000) and using a WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows displayed:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           distinct JSON_OBJECT(
                   'id' VALUE c1,
                   'value' VALUE c2,
                   'description'  VALUE c3) RETURNING VARCHAR2(32000))
  FROM test
WHERE ROWNUM < 500;
```

The WHERE clause can contain any condition that will reduce the number of rows to be diplayed.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to test it like below.

```sql
create table TEST_TABLE(c1 number, c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(100));
begin
  for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
    insert into TEST_TABLE values (i, 'val_' || i, 'descption of ' || i);
  end loop;
end;
/
Commit;
```

```sql
SELECT id, value, description
FROM json_table(  ( SELECT J_ARR
                    FROM (Select J_ARR
                          From  ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                                         distinct
                                         JSON_OBJECT(
                                           'id'          VALUE c1,
                                           'value'       VALUE c2,
                                           'description' VALUE c3
                                         )
                                         RETURNING CLOB
                                      ) "J_ARR"
                                  FROM  TEST_TABLE
                                ) 
                         )
                    ) , '$[*]'
                    COLUMNS ( id NUMBER PATH '$.id',
                              value VARCHAR PATH '$.value',
                              description VARCHAR PATH '$.description'
                            )
               ) 
/*    R e s u l t :
ID   VALUE    DESCRIPTION
---- -------- -------------
   1 val_1    descption of 1
   2 val_2    descption of 2
   3 val_3    descption of 3
... ... ...
 999 val_999    descption of 999
1000 val_1000   descption of 1000  */
```

If this test gives the same result in your SQLDeveloper then it is a fact that result of your code from the question IS A PROPPER AND COMPLETE JSON ARRAY OF THREE FIELDS. Why you don't see that in your SQLDeveloper's Query Result Grid (not in Script Output which will truncate it) is impossible to say. The thing is that if the result of your JSON ARRAY generation was in any way false this test will end in error.
*"Can anyone help me to understand what should I do to get all the rows, please?"*
To make it short: If the test works then you should do nothing - you already have all the rows.
**Addition**:
Run command from picture to see the length of your array and do it as in the picture:
[image]

Alternative is :

1. click the cell (it should get blue background)
2. Ctrl + C (copy)
3. Open any text editor and Ctrl + V (paste)

OR

1. doubleclick the cell (background stays white)
2. Ctrl + A (select all) (background changes to blue)
3. Ctrl + C (copy)
4. Open any text editor and Ctrl + V (paste)

Comment: The output is the same as SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE; This is not what I expect. I expect the output to be a JSON file format with an array of the 3 fields.

Comment: @mikcutu And it is just that. The innermost query is from your question. In my SQLDeveloper's grid view it is a JSON array. This test above takes that array and successfuly extracts those three values. If you get the result as in my answer then it is JSON array. If it was not the test would end with error. There is still a problem for you if your SQLDeveloper doesn't show the result as it should be. In that case the problem is in SQLDeveloper and not within your Select JSON_ARRAYAGG(........)

Comment: @d r, yes, the test itself is correct; the script is correct, but the way it is displayed the output is the problem. The problem do not occur if I use PL SQL Developer. Also, if I restrict the number of rows used in my SELECT statement, i can manage to waive the error. Maybe, you can share the settings you have in SQL Developer that displays correctly the entire content of JSON file.

Comment: @mikcutu First, there is no file, it is a column containing json array with 1000 elements and three label value pairs in each element. So, it is a json object. SQL Developer has two run icons on toolbar, one for script output and one for query result grid. By default settings grid will show table with rows and columns fitting them to screen. Overcrowded cell, if doubleclicked, gets a pencil icon. Click the pencil and Voila! If you don't see it then I'd like to see your settings.

Comment: @d r, I understand what you say, but trust me, there is no pencil icon and everting the cell contains is what I posted above. Indeed, it looks to be an SQL Developer problem, not a database problem.